# Long press word in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'd like to use the feature of returning a word in a UIWebView. When I long press a word gets highlighted. How can I see how the system identifies single words? The UItext view has granularity to work with but does the UIWebView have anything similar?

Comment: Yes `webview` also have the similar functionality

Comment: what is the function? How do I access it? I am trying to use java script and i keep getting a return of undefined.